# How to use backgroundpage to stay a value which used in an inject js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
{  
    "name": "coffee",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "version": "1.0",  
    "description": "coffee test",  
    "browser_action": {  
       "default_icon": "icon.png" ,
       "default_title": "My Task List",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
     },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
     "content_scripts": [{
         "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*" ], 
         "js": ["inject.js"], 
         "run_at": "document_end",
         "all_frames": true 
    }],
    "permissions": [   
     "tabs", "http://*/*","https://*/*"  
    ]   
}
```

manifest.josn

```
count=1;
```

background.js

```
var bgpg=chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
if(bgpg)
{
    alert("ok");
    if(bgpg.count>=0){
        bgpg.count=bgpg.count+1;
    }else{
        bgpg.count=0;
    }
    alert(bgpg.count);

}else{alert("NO");}
```

inject.js.

It didn't alter anything.In fact,last week I succeed to use the background value,but today I totally can't find where I am wrong.

Comment: It seems you have a typo with if statement. `if(bgpg.count=>0)` should be `if(bgpg.count>=0)`.

Comment: Thanks,I have change it,but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Is `inject.js` a content script? Where do you execute it and how you include it?

Comment: Have you considered [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)? The more standard way to set and get values between the background page and content script would be via message passing.

Comment: @Xan I update a total mainifest.The inject.js can work anything such as  alert(1); except to get the backgroundpage value.When it run at the var bgpg=chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage(); statement,it will stop and no continue to run

Comment: @br1ckb0t I will try it,I am new to chrome extension,it is the first time I see it.Thanks

Comment: @Louise ok - good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A content script cannot call `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`, this is too high privilege for it.

For security reasons content scripts [have very limited access to Chrome APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). A background page has full access, and as such directly manipulating it is forbidden. Your code throws an error and stops.

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use `chrome.*` APIs, with the exception of:
>
>   - `extension` ( `getURL` , `inIncognitoContext` , `lastError` , `onRequest` , `sendRequest` )
>   - [...]

You will need to use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to communicate with the background page; however, if all you need is some data you can try using [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) - it's shared between the two.